# Semi-simple commutative algebra

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $A$ be a semi-simple commutative algebra over a field $F$, and $F$ is algebraically closed.
The proposition is that we can express $A=Fe_1 \oplus ... \oplus Fe_n$, where $e_i$ are orthogonal idempotents. How to prove this?

I know that by Artin-Wedderburn theorem $A$ is isomorphic as a ring to direct product of fields.

Comment: I would assume that you assume $A$ to be finite dimensional as well. In that case $A$ is (as you mentioned by Artin-Wedderburn) a direct sum of extension fields of $F$ and each of these fields is f.d. and hence algebraic over $F$...

Comment: Yes, but when and how do these idempotents appear?

Comment: Well, they are exactly the "unit elements" of the fields $A$ decomposes into. Algorithmically finding them might be a rather hard problem depending on $F$...

Comment: Why must they be orthogonal?

Comment: Because that's what Artin-Wedderburn says. Let's say we identify $A$ with the cartesian product $F \times F$ (only two components for simplicity) with component-wise operation via Artin-Wedderburn. Then the idempotents are $e_1=(1,0)$ and $e_2=(0,1)$ and by definition of multiplication in a direct product it is $e_1e_2=e_2e_1=0$...

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Central idempotents in rings with identity are directly tied to ring decompositions into a product of ideals. (In commutative rings, these are *all* idempotents, of course.)

You can easily prove this lemma:

> If $I$ and $J$ are ideals of a ring $R$ with identity such that $I\oplus J=R$, then there exist two central idempotents $e,f$ such that $eR=I$, $fR=J$. (*Hint*: the obvious candidates arise from $e+f=1$.)

You can easily state and prove a version for $\bigoplus_{i=1}^n I_i=R$ if you can solve this special case.

That pretty much answers how "the idempotents appear."

For the question about orthogonality, you should see that if $I\oplus J$ is a *direct* sum of ideals, then $ij=0$ for any $i\in I$, $j\in J$, because $ij\in I\cap J=\{0\}$.